# Having issue with Scan.io or scanning credit cards in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am trying to use [Scan.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) framework to scan only card numbers, but actually doesn't work ! it detect cards but doesn't scan !! even I tried its both sample projects in Swift and Obj C but detects nothing ! I tried with 5 different cards. I tested with  Pay card scan and it worked.

Here is my codes (Swift 3.0) :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate {


  @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    CardIOUtilities.preload()



  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


    @IBAction func scan(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let cardIOVC = CardIOPaymentViewController(paymentDelegate: self)
        present(cardIOVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func userDidCancel(_ paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {

        print("cancel")
        _ = self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func userDidProvide(_ cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, in paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {

        print("enter manually")
        _ = self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    //THIS FUNCTION NOT WORK AT ALL ! 
    func userDidProvideCreditCardInfo(cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, inPaymentViewController paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {

        if let info = cardInfo {
//            let str = NSString(format: "Received card info.\n Number: %@\n expiry: %02lu/%lu\n cvv: %@.", info.redactedCardNumber, info.expiryMonth, info.expiryYear, info.cvv)

            let cardNumber = NSString(format: "Received card info.\n Number: %@:",info.cardNumber)
            resultLabel.text = String(cardNumber)

        }

         _ = self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Does iOS provide any public API for developers to scan credit cards ? Or is there any better solutions ? Thanks